# Nil while unwrapping outlet in custom uiview from xib Swift

Tags: swift, customview

Сделал `UIView`: `.xib` файл, указал в `File's Owner` название класса наследника от `UIView`.

Затем сделал инициалзацию

```
@IBDesignable class Search: UIView {

    var view = UIView()
    var nibName = "Search"

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        // setup the view from .xib
        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = self.bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]

        addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        // grabs the appropriate bundle
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        return view
    }
}
```

Все шаги как по туториалу. Этот `UIView` реализует поиск, а следовательно мне потребовалось сделать outlet `UITextField` и настроить его

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchField: UITextField!

@IBInspectable var hint : String {
    get {
        let value = searchField.placeholder
        return value == nil ? "" : value!
    } set {
        configureSearchField(newValue)
    }
}

func configureSearchField(name : String) {
    searchField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: name, attributes: [
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Semibold", size: 12.0)!,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()
        ])
}
```

Есть ещё параметры, которые хотелось бы учесть, но на этом моменте я поймал `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` на попытке обратиться к `UITextField`, следовательно он не инициализируется должным то образом до обращения к нему. Предвосхищая вопросы могу сказать

1. `File's Owner` у меня указан корректно
2. nibName соответствует названию файла в проекте
3. В Connections Inspector нет никаких варнингов или ошибок, связь сделана правильно

Что я мог упустить?

Comment: 4) Я уверен, что ошибку вызывает не попытка обратиться к шрифту, а именно к UITextField так как я пытался обращаться и к другим методам.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Объяснение по fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569349/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-v)

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, нет, не дубликат. Мне известно, что такое опционал в Swift и что значит unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. Этот же вопрос посвящен тому, что абсолютно непонятно, почему эта ошибка вылезает в данном конкретном случае.

Comment: в какой строке креш?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko,  на попытке засетить searchField.attributedPlaceholder (второй кусок кода, первое обращение к searchField)

Comment: положите весь код куда нибудь, я посмотрю

Comment: боюсь это невозможно, вопросу 2 месяца. Я ушел от этой проблемы так ее и не решив.

Comment: тем более давайте закрывать

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko ну а может кто нибудь столкнется, и выльется в дискуссию, я сейчас попробую переименовать чтобы суть точнее выразить

Comment: не думаю, что иметь вопрос на который невозможно ответить, поскольку в нем недостаточно данных, хорошая идея

Comment: Вы модератор, Вам виднее.

Comment: я не модератор, я ответственный гражданин