# Объяснение по fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift

На сегодняшний день у нас есть 6 практически одинаковых вопросов по сабжу. Давайте один раз напишем полный ответ по этому вопросу и будем в будущем на него ссылаться. Пока публикую под своим именем, если будут добавления/редактирования переставим на сообщество.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Давайте один последний раз пройдемся по unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value и больше никогда к нему не будем возвращаться.

Когда вы создаете переменные инстанса, swift от вас хочет, чтобы вы либо сразу им присвоили значения по дефолту, либо инициализировали их в init. Во многих случаях это нам не подходит, тогда мы объявляем свои переменные как optional.

```
var test:Int? // вопрос в конце, это объявление опциональной переменной
```

Что значит Optional? Это значит, что вместо просто переменной, например Int, мы получаем инумерацию из двух значений: `none` и `some(Wrapped)`. Вот это Wrapped и есть значение нашей переменной.

Соответственно, если переменная не присвоена, то при попытке к ней обратиться, получим `none` т.е. nil.

Если же она содержит значение мы получим `Optional(value)`

Вот пример:

```
var test:Int?
print(test) // напечатает 'nil'
test = 42
print(test) // напечатает 'Optional(42)'
```

Далее, чтобы избавиться от этого Optional нам надо ее развернуть (unwrap), то есть сказать, что мы точно уверены, что там что то есть и мы хотим получить это самое что то. Другими словами, вместо `Optional(value)`, получить `value`. Чтобы сделать принудительное разворачивание (forced unwrap) мы добавляем '!'. При этом, если переменная не присвоена, мы получим крэш - тот самый unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Пример:

```
var test:Int?
print(test!) // крэш unexpectedly found nil и т.д.

var test2:Int?
test2 = 42
print(test2!) // напечатает 42
```

Дальше, если мы хотим создать переменную как Optional, но точно знаем, что в нее будет что-то присвоено до того, как мы ее будем читать первый раз, мы можем ее объявить как Implicitly Unwrapped Optional Type, посредством добавления '!' в объявлении. В этом случае, она опять же будет Optional, но система будет ее принудительно разворачивать (force unwrap) при любом обращении к ней.

```
var test:Int! // '!' в конце, это обявление implicitly unwrapped optional
print(test) // крэш unexpectedly found nil...

var test2:Int!
test2 = 42
print(test2) // напечатает 42
```

А что делать, если мы понятия не имеем есть там что то в этой optional или нет?

```
var test:Int?
if(test != nil) {
    print(test!) // развернутое значение
} else {
    print(test) // nil
}
```

Либо другой способ, который создает временную переменную с развернутым значением

```
var test:Int?
if let unwrappedTest = test {
    print(unwrappedTest)
} else {
    print("no value")
}
```

**UPDATE:** то же самое через guard

```
var test:Int?
guard let unwrappedTest = test else {
    print("No value")
    return // либо throw по ситуации
}

print(unwrappedTest)
```

Ну и если вам надо force unwrapped превратить обратно в Optional:

```
var test:Int!
print(test as Optional) // напечатает nil
```

**Optional chaining:**

Есть еще такая ситуация, когда надо сделать цепочку вызовов, при этом где то в цепочке может содержаться опциональная перменная.

Вот такой пример дает apple:

Допустим есть класс Residence, и в нем есть переменная numberOfRooms; и есть класс Person, который имеет опциональную переменную типа Residence. Другими словами у человека может быть жилье, с каким то количеством комнат,  а может и не быть жилья. То есть при попытке обратиться к человек-жилье-комнаты, мы можем наткнуться на nil вместо жилья.

```
class Person {
    var residence: Residence?
}

class Residence {
    var numberOfRooms = 1
}
```

Теперь мы хотим создать новый Person, и узнать сколько комнат в его жилище (при этом residence может быть nil поскольку он Optional). Для этого мы говорим системе, что мы хотим делать с опциональным значением - либо оставлять его опциональным ('?') со всеми вытекающими последствиями, в частности получить nil вместо количества комнат; либо принудительно его разворачивать, при этом имея риск получить fatal error.

```
let john = Person()
print(john.residence!.numberOfRooms) // крэш unexpectedly ...
print(john.residence?.numberOfRooms) // напечатает nil

let tom = Person()
tom.residence = Residence()
print(tom.residence!.numberOfRooms) // напечатает 1
print(tom.residence?.numberOfRooms) // напечатает Optional(1)
```

Тут надо заметить, что хотя numberOfRooms не является опциональной, она в этой цепи становится таковой, поскольку цепь идет через опциональную `residence?`