# Базовый вопрос по свифту

Tags: ios, swift

Начал читать документацию по свифту и вот первый вопрос

Вот есть код

```
var optionalString: String? = "Hello"
print(optionalString == nil)

var optionalName: String? = "John Appleseed"
var greeting = "Hello!"
if let name = optionalName {
greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

И вот вопросы :

1. `var optionalString: String? = "Hello"` - написано, что мы ставим
   `?` , чтоб отметить что это присвоение не обязательное

   > Write a question mark (?) after the type of a value to mark the value as optional.

Что значит не обязательное? В смысле если я хочу оставить это значение пустым, вот так `var optionalString: String? = ""` ?

2. Теперь вот это условие `if let name = optionalName`. Я так это вижу создается переменная `let name` и если `optionalName` не равно `nil` (я так понимаю, что это тоже самое, что в java `null`) , то условие работает.

Но тогда если это проверка на nil почему нельзя было написать, что то вроде `if optionalName != nil`? Зачем создавать лишнюю переменную?

3. И последнее "Hello, (name)", я так понял, что вот такой синтаксис `\()` мы используем когда хотим сконвертировать допустим `int` в `String`

Но зачем мы его используем в этом примере, когда у нас явно все в `Sring`-ах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну попробую:

1) '?' значит, что эта переменная может быть не инизиализирована, другими словами не содержать значения. То есть, можно написать `var optionalString: String?` и тогда при обращении к ней будет возвращать nil. по этой теме посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569349/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-v)

2) Это называется optional binding, и широко применяется в swift для случаев, где переменная может быть nil. Ваше замечание про `if optionalName != nil` вполне уместно, просто создатели swift посчитали, что использовать развернутую константу удобнее, чем каждый раз разворачивать optional в if-else (помните, что вы можете сделать и if var, если надо).
Например, допустим у вас есть опциональная переменная, и вы хотите вывести ее значение

```
var hello:String? = "123"

if(hello != nil) {
    print(hello!) // обратите внимание на '!' - без него результат будет "Optional(123)"
} else {
    print("empty")
}

if let const = hello {
    print(const)
} else {
    print("empty")
}
```

3) синтаксис `\(varName)` используется, чтобы при создании строки использовать переменные/константы и так далее, то есть

```
let name = "Max"
print ("hello \(name)") // напечатает "Hello Max"
```

для сравнения в objC это выглядело бы так

```
NSString *name = @"Max";
NSLog(@"Hello %@", name);
```

другой пример:

```
let digit = 1
let anotherDigit = 2
print("sum \(digit+anotherDigit)") // напечетает "sum 3"
```

Comment: 1)Вопрос насчет вот такого синтаксиса `var hello:String? = "123"` нужно ли указывать `?` если мы все равно явно сразу присваиваем значение?   2) По вопросу №3 мой вопрос был в том, что не совсем понятно зачем указывать `\()` если явно все в стрингах? Для сравнения в java `sout("Hello" + String.valeuOf(34));` так вот `String.valeuOf(34)` указываем для того чтоб привести тип `int` в `String` , но если бы мы передавали сразу стринг то приводить не нужно было бы вот так `sout("Hello" + "34");` Но в свифт я так понял не имеет значения какой тип всегда ставим `\()`, так?

Comment: 1) в вашей конкретной ситуации '?' там не нужен. В ситуации, когда вы, например, создаете переменную инстанса, и не присваиваете ей значение в ините, вы получите ошибку при компиляции. в этом случае, поставив  '?' вы говорите компилятору, что вас устраивает, что она не инициализирована, и вы присвоите ей значение позже. 2) не знаю как это по другому объяснить, короче '\' это escape character, то есть то, что идет после него надо интерпретировать. то есть `print("\(2+3)")` выведет "5" а не "\(2+3)"

Comment: )) ладно спрошу по другому) Вот  так можно написать `let name = "Max"
print ("hello " + name)` .  ? Компилятор поймет , что `name` тоже является `String` ? Компилятор просто сможет присоединить `String` к `Sring`?

Comment: да, можно. эскейпы по моему просто читать проще `"next year \(name) will be \(age+1)"` или `"next year " + name + "will be " + String.valueOf(age+1)"`